# Create New SQL Table w/o duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm learning how to create tables in SQL pulling data from existing tables from two different databases. I am trying to create a table combining two tables without duplicates. I've seen some say using UNION but I could not get that to work.

Say TABLE 1 has 2 COLUMNS (IdNumber, Material) and TABLE 2 has 3 COLUMNS (IdNumber, Size, Description)

How can I create a new table (named TABLE3) that combines those two but only shows the columns (PartDescription, Weight, Color) but without duplicates.

What I have done so far is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Materialsearch (IdNumber varchar(30), Material varchar(30))
CREATE TABLE #Sizesearch (idnumber varchar(30), Size varchar(30), Description varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #Materialsearch (IdNumber, Material)
SELECT [IdNumber],[Material]
FROM [datalist].[dbo].[Table1]
WHERE Material LIKE 'Steel' AND IdNumber NOT LIKE 'Steel'

INSERT INTO #Sizesearch (idnumber, Size, Description)
SELECT [idNumber],[itemSize], [ShortDesc]
FROM [515dap].[dbo].[Table2]
WHERE itemSize LIKE '1' AND idnumber NOT LIKE 'Steel'

SELECT DISTINCT #Materialsearch.IdNumber, #Materialsearch.Material, 
            #Sizesearch.Size, #Sizesearch.Description 
FROM #Materialsearch 
INNER JOIN #Sizesearch 
     ON #Materialsearch.IdNumber = #Sizesearch.idnumber
ORDER BY #Materialsearch.IdNumber

DROP TABLE #Materialsearch
DROP TABLE #Sizesearch
```

This would show all items that are made from steel but do not have steel as their itemid's.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand what result set you are looking for.

Comment: Sample data is a must here.

Comment: `LIKE` without wildcards, `%`, should be replaced with `=`.

Comment: I want the resulting list to show only material and corresponding size.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS "Combine" means nothing in particular. You are not saying what you want. This is not clear.  Wrong code does not help to say what correct code would do. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. [ask] [help]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after - but you may find this useful.

You could use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which takes takes all rows from both tables, matches the ones it can, then reports all rows.

I'd suggest (for your understanding) running

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM #Materialsearch AS A
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Sizesearch AS B ON A.[IdNumber] = B.[IdNumber]
```

Then to get the relevant data, you just need some tweaks on that e.g.,

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(A.[IdNumber], B.[IdNumber]) AS [IdNumber], 
    A.Material, 
    B.Size, 
    B.Description
FROM #Materialsearch AS A
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Sizesearch AS B ON A.[IdNumber] = B.[IdNumber]
```

Edit: Changed typoed INNER JOINs to FULL OUTER JOINs. Oops :( Thankyou very much @Thorsten for finding it!

Comment: I, too, think that the OP is looking for a full outer join. But why do you think they should try queries with inner joins instead? Are these typos?

Comment: Oops! Thanks @Thorsten. Major typo! Finger memory.